# How to find if two Numpy arrays have same items?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two Numpy arrays A and B, I want to find whether `sorted(A) == sorted(B)` or not? For ex: If `A = [5,3,2,4]` and `B = [3,2,5,4]`, then it should evaluate to `True`.

Can this be achieved in linear time?

Comment: set(A) == set(B)

Comment: set doesn't work if the lists have repeat values that must match up.

Comment: Ya right @MikeSperry suppose if `A = [1,1,2,3]` and `B = [3,1,2]`, then `set(A)==set(B)` would return TRUE but the answer is actually False. @Lamanus

Comment: What's wrong with `sorted(A) == sorted(B)` in your case?  Can you tell us more about your constraints?

Comment: what about numpy.unique(a) == numpy.unique(b)

Comment: @MikeSperry The size of the list could be as large as 10^8, so I was looking for a more optimized method like something in O(n).

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Take a look at my O(n) solution below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about Counter from collections

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.Counter([1,1,2,3])
>>> b = collections.Counter([3,1,2])
>>> a == b
False

>>> a = collections.Counter([1,1,2,3])
>>> b = collections.Counter([3,1,2,1])
>>> a == b
True
```

Construction happens in O(n) time for each list

edit: If anyone is unfamiliar with what counter does. It goes through the list and creates what is essentially a dictionary mapping of value to the number of occurrences that value.
So once we create these dictionaries of the form `a = {'1': 2, '2': 1...}` Which takes up to O(n) time we can compare the two dictionaries which also takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

In this case adding brackets works quite fast:

```
A = [5,3,2,4]
B = [3,2,5,4]
print((sorted(A) == sorted(B)))
```

Which yields:

```
True
```

Comment: if there is a dupe for ex, A = [1,1,2,3] and B = [1,2,3] it will not be same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If `a` and `b` are

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,3,2,3,4])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

then,

```
np.array_equal(np.unique(a), np.unique(b))
True
```